# Change price from single product input hidden field in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, custom-fields, price

I Would like to set a custom price when product is added to cart, based on an input hidden field located in the single product page.

I have tried to use this code to change the product price in cart:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
        $custom_price = $_POST['_custom_price'];
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            // for WooCommerce version 3+ use:
            $value['data']->set_price($custom_price);

        }
}
```

But I get a zero price.

Here is [my test page](http://www.alyssabooking.com/produit/sentido-phenicia/). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks for help but it dosent work...it give an error
this is my function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    if(isset($_POST['_custom_price'] )){
        $custom_price = $_POST['_custom_price'];
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            // for WooCommerce version 3+ use:
            $value['data']->set_price($custom_price);
            $_SESSION['custom_price']=$custom_price;
        }
    }else{

    }

}

// STACK HELP CODE
/*
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_price', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_price( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
    // Only when option is passed through the URL
    if( ! isset($_POST['_custom_price']) && empty($_POST['_custom_price']) )
        return $cart_item_data;

    $cart_item_data['custom_price'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_price'] );

    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_price' );
function set_custom_price( $cart ) {
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( isset($cart_item['custom_price']) ){
            $value['data']->set_price($cart_item['custom_price']);
        }
    }
}

*/


?>


<?php

/*
 * Display input on single product page
 * @return html
 */
function kia_custom_option(){
    $value = isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) : '';
    printf( '<label>%s</label><input id="hotel_chambre_selected" name="_custom_option" value="%s" />', __( '', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'kia_custom_option', 9 );





/*
 * Validate when adding to cart
 * @param bool $passed
 * @param int $product_id
 * @param int $quantity
 * @return bool
 */
function kia_add_to_cart_validation($passed, $product_id, $qty){

    if( isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) && sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) == '' ){
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s cannot be added to the cart until you enter some custom text.', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), $product->get_title() ), 'error' );
        return false;
    }

    return $passed;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'kia_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );






/*
* Add custom data to the cart item
* @param array $cart_item
* @param int $product_id
* @return array
*/
function kia_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

     if( isset( $_POST['_custom_option'] ) ) {
             $cart_item['custom_option'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_option'] );
     }

     return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'kia_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );




/*
 * Load cart data from session
 * @param array $cart_item
 * @param array $other_data
 * @return array
 */
function kia_get_cart_item_from_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

    if ( isset( $values['custom_option'] ) ){
        $cart_item['custom_option'] = $values['custom_option'];
    }

    return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'kia_get_cart_item_from_session', 20, 2 );





/*
 * Add meta to order item
 * @param int $item_id
 * @param array $values
 * @return void
 */
function kia_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {

    if ( ! empty( $values['custom_option'] ) ) {
        woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'custom_option', $values['custom_option'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'kia_add_order_item_meta', 10, 2 );




/*
 * Get item data to display in cart
 * @param array $other_data
 * @param array $cart_item
 * @return array
 */
function kia_get_item_data( $other_data, $cart_item ) {

    if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_option'] ) ){

        $other_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Votre chambre ', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'value' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['custom_option'] )
        );

    }

    return $other_data;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'kia_get_item_data', 10, 2 );



/*
 * Show custom field in order overview
 * @param array $cart_item
 * @param array $order_item
 * @return array
 */
function kia_order_item_product( $cart_item, $order_item ){

    if( isset( $order_item['custom_option'] ) ){
        $cart_item_meta['custom_option'] = $order_item['custom_option'];
    }

    return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', 'kia_order_item_product', 10, 2 );



/*
 * Add the field to order emails
 * @param array $keys
 * @return array
 */
function kia_email_order_meta_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['custom_field'] = __( 'Votre chambre ', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'kia_email_order_meta_fields');



/*
 * Order Again
 * @param array $cart_item
 * @param array $order_item
 * @param obj $order
 * @return array
 */
function kia_order_again_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $order_item, $order ){

    if( isset( $order_item['custom_option'] ) ){
        $cart_item_meta['custom_option'] = $order_item['custom_option'];
    }

    return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_again_cart_item_data', 'kia_order_again_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
```

this is the [result](http://alyssabooking.com/wp-content/themes/sparkling/assets/images/Capture.PNG) of print_r($_POST) in my function

Comment: Please, provide more detailed description

Comment: I have removed my code as it's conflicting with your other actual code that doesn't work anyway, as on your test web site, you never get the value inside your other hidden custom field "hotel_chambre_selected". So you need to solve that problem before (as there are no rooms displayed and selectable in the first process). The error is due to 2 things: 1. a typo error… 2. You need to remove Your old initial code function. But as there is no rooms selectable you will not get any price on the price hidden field.

Comment: Thank you for the answer..
I have not yet added the JS function that selects a room but initially there is a value in the hotel_chambre_selected field and the Hidden price field.
and on that basis that I want to work because I block at that point.
I added print_r ($ _ POST) in my code and I find a value for the price and the room in the card page when submitting the form card.
but when i click on "details et finalisation" then $ _POST is empty